# How can I access objects under INFORMATION_SCHEMA in a DB in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I access objects under INFORMATION_SCHEMA in a DB in Snowflake?

If I try to grant USAGE access to a PUBLIC or any role on INFORMATION_SCHEMA I get this error: SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'

I am trying to access objects under INFORMATION_SCHEMA from Power BI. Would be possible to do this..?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of views and table functions in a databases's INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Some require elevated permissions, but if you just want basic access for a role all it needs is `usage` on the database:

```
use role ACCOUNTADMIN;
create or replace role NEWROLE;
grant usage on database TEST to NEWROLE;
grant role NEWROLE to user MYUSER;
use role NEWROLE;
select * from "TEST"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS";
```

Answer (score 0):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA is at the DB level, I believe so long as you have usage access at the DB level, you should be able to access INFORMATION_SCHEMA underneath it, as Greg's example has suggested.

But the result from INFORMATION_SCHEMA can be dependent on the user's access. For example, if the user does not have access to certain tables, then they won't appear in the results.